# The session id is too long or contains illegal characters in Laravel 4

Tags: installation, laravel, laravel-4

I installed Laravel 4.0 and got this error

> ErrorException
>   SessionHandler::read(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
>           return (bool) $this->handler->close();
>       }
>       /**
>        * {@inheritdoc}
>        */
>       public function read($id)
>       {
>           return (string) $this->handler->read($id);
>       }
>       /**

Comment: Do you have a Laravel 3 installation running locally as well. I do see this issue popping around around and it might be the case. Do note that both Laravel 3 and Laravel 4 using the same cookie name "laravel_session" by default.

Answer (score 44):

Do you have Laravel 3 installed on the same machine? By default, Laravel 4 uses the same session cookie name (as Laravel 3), now found in /app/config/session.php file. Simply change:

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
```

to, e.g.

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session_4',
```

and refresh browser. All should work now.

Answer (score 11):

It could be that you have a corrupt cookie. Try clearing cookies in your browser.

Take a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16318456/1563189

Especially:

> How do you end up with illegal characters in PHPSESSID in the first place? Aren't they generated by PHP automatically? – `Lèse majesté` Jul 6 '10 at 11:57
>
> They are, but a cookie that links you to a generated session id is client side. If that cookie changes to an invalid format (somebody is trying to exploit something) PHP will notice it. – `Aleksey Korzun` Sep 6 '11 at 19:56

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug report for this problem (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68063)

You can check the success of your session_start and generate the id if needed:

```
$ok = @session_start();
if(!$ok){
session_regenerate_id(true); // replace the Session ID
session_start(); 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I think it's a more generic automatic fix for this kind of issues, however they happen.