# Yii session_start throwing config details

Tags: php, session, yii

I have an application in Yii(1.15) framework. I recently got this issue

```
Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
```

along with all the config details saved in protected/config/main.php.
How to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are

Comment: Yii framework should handle this issue.

Comment: @topherkanyuga, how can I reproduce this issue? still wondering..