# Symfony on WAMP produces error "The session id is too long or contains illegal characters"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, wamp

I am working with php, symfony and wamp, and I am getting this error.

> Warning: SessionHandler::read(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'

The server is working on the app perfectly but when I am testing on the server I get this error. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are/16318456#16318456 Also try by delete you cookies.

Comment: @Seer it's a Schroedinger's Server

Comment: If I remember correctly, this could also mean that `PHPSESSID` exists but it is empty?

Comment: yeah but I think I solved it

Comment: @daroum can you suggest how you fixed that one? I am getting the same issue but not seeing any proper solution.