# session_regenerate_id is not creating a new session id

Tags: php, session, session-state

I have a script which is meant to finish the current session and start a new one. There is a segment of code I use and it works fine on my development computer. However, when I posted it to the production server, the session id is constantly remaining the same.

The following is my code for restarting the session:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();
$_POST = array();
$_GET = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), 
              '', 
              time() - 42000,
              $params["path"], 
              $params["domain"],
              $params["secure"], 
              $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
session_start();    

session_regenerate_id(true);
```

On the last line, a new session id is not generated.

Why would this be different between two servers running PHP? And what can I do to correct it?

Comment: what are you doing there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimenting I solved the problem.

The session_regenerate_id(true) line does not regenerate a new session id if any text has been written into the response. I already had a series of echo statements issuing text for debugging purposes and after I removed them new session ids were created.

Answer (score 2):

session_regenerate_id() updates the current session id with a newly generated one. It does not change session variables.

```
echo session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
echo session_id();
```

You should unset session to do that:

```
unset($_SESSION); // or
$_SESSION = array();
```

How to start a new session:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id();
unset($_SESSION);
session_start();
```

Comment: I have tried that as well and unfortunately the session id is still remaining the same.

Comment: Actually, this code works if the cookie is destroyed as well.