# session_start() issues regarding illegal characters, empty session ID and failed session

Tags: php, apache, session

**So, I realise this is a repeat question** however, it is apprently a bug yet the original post for this is 5 years old but it's also said that it's a malicious attack... [The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are)

What is the latest, **correct way** of dealing with this issue?

My error logs show:

> [30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
>
> [30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cusplugin/cusplugin.php on line 21
>
> [30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cusplugin/cusplugin.php on line 377
>
> [30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cusplugin/cusplugin.php on line 718
>
> [30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
>
> [30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

### My full logs:

```
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[30-Sep-2015 11:12:37 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 718
[30-Sep-2015 11:12:37 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 718
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2015 10:12:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[30-Sep-2015 10:13:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[30-Sep-2015 10:13:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[30-Sep-2015 10:13:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[30-Sep-2015 10:13:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 718
[30-Sep-2015 10:13:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[01-Oct-2015 05:47:22 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[01-Oct-2015 05:47:22 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 718
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 377
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[01-Oct-2015 04:47:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[01-Oct-2015 23:10:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 492
[01-Oct-2015 23:11:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 492[02-Oct-2015 08:59:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[02-Oct-2015 09:59:42 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 739
[02-Oct-2015 09:59:42 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 739
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[02-Oct-2015 08:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[03-Oct-2015 04:51:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(ABSPATHwp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 04:51:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(ABSPATHwp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 04:51:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 09:09:49 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 727
[03-Oct-2015 09:09:49 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 727
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function check_connection() on a non-object in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-press/sp-api/sp-api-wpdb.php on line 439
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wl-coupon/wishlist-coupon20.php on line 27
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 385
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session with empty session ID in /home/HOSTINGACCOUNT/public_html/wp-content/plugins/customplugin/customplugin.php on line 21
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
[03-Oct-2015 08:09:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

As you can see there they all seem to happen in groups just look at 30th of september it happens loads of times all within 1 min then doesn't happen the rest of the day...

It's throwing the sessionid issue up for customplugin, simple press forums (I think),  and Wishlist Coupon 2.0

My customplugin code has:

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

**I've tried option 2 from below but it didn't help/fix the problem.**

A snippet of the other WordPress plugin that is causing the some of the error(s):

```
class WishListCoupon20 extends WishListPlugin {
    public function __construct($file, $slug, $sku, $name, $link_name, $prefix, $require_wlm) {
        parent::__construct($file, $slug, $sku, $name, $link_name, $prefix, $require_wlm);

        session_start();
```

The other stack overflow post has a few variations of working around the issue but I am not sure what is correct because the post is 5+ years old and you would expect a bug to have been fixed in that time.

### Option 1 thanks to Sergey Eremin:

```
<?php
    function my_session_start()
    {
        if (ini_get('session.use_cookies') && isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
            $sessid = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
        } elseif (!ini_get('session.use_only_cookies') && isset($_GET['PHPSESSID'])) {
            $sessid = $_GET['PHPSESSID'];
        } else {
            session_start();
            return false;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/', $sessid)) {
            return false;
        }
        session_start();

        return true;
    }
?>
```

### Option 2 thanks to danjfoley:

```
try {
   session_start();
} catch(ErrorExpression $e) {
   session_regenerate_id();
   session_start();
}
```

### Option 3 thanks to Cendak (using Andron's previous solution)

```
function my_session_start()
{
      $sn = session_name();
      if (isset($_COOKIE[$sn])) {
          $sessid = $_COOKIE[$sn];
      } else if (isset($_GET[$sn])) {
          $sessid = $_GET[$sn];
      } else {
          return session_start();
      }

     if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,40}$/', $sessid)) {
          return false;
      }
      return session_start();
}

if ( !my_session_start() ) {
    session_id( uniqid() );
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

### Option 4 thanks to Andron:

```
<?php
    function my_session_start()
    {
        $sn = session_name();
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$sn])) {
            $sessid = $_COOKIE[$sn];
        } else if (isset($_GET[$sn])) {
            $sessid = $_GET[$sn];
        } else {
            session_start();
            return false;
        }

       if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,40}$/', $sessid)) {
            return false;
        }
        session_start();

       return true;
    }
?>
```

### Option 5 thanks to alpere:

```
$ok = @session_start();
if(!$ok){
session_regenerate_id(true); // replace the Session ID
session_start(); 
}
```

## Or... is there a better way.

Comment: Which `php` version are you using ? Are you the admin of the server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The problem:**

`session_start()` relies on `$_COOKIE[session_name()]`, so, if you edit the cookie value to something like `#$#$FDSFSR#"#"$"#$"` or simply empty it (not delete the cookie) and refresh a page with your code:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

The following warning is generated:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains
> illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in
> /home/username/public_html/session_start.php on line 7

This happens because `php` is checking if `session_id()` exists and, in fact, it exists, but contains illegal characters not allowed as `session_id` name.

A **valid** `session id` may contain **only** digits, letters A to Z (both upper and lower case), comma and dash (`[-,a-zA-Z0-9]`) between **1** and **128** characters.

---

**My solution:**

Check if `$_COOKIE[session_name()]` is set and contains a valid `session_id` prior to `session_start()`, otherwise, delete the session cookie and only then  `session_start()`, something like:

```
function safeSession() {
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) AND preg_match('/^[-,a-zA-Z0-9]{1,128}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        session_start();
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
        session_start(); 
    } else {
        session_start(); 
    }
}
```

start the session:

```
safeSession();
```

---

**NOTES:**

1 - `session_name` is defined on your `php.ini` as `session.name = SOMETHING` (default is `PHPSESSID`), so, you may be looking for a cookie matching `session.name`. You can use the `session_name()` function to retrieve it.

2 - Session cookie manipulation can be used by hackers to dump information from your server (`username` and `path`) if `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` is set.

3 - `session_regenerate_id(true)` works but, because it checks the current `session_id` prior to assign a new one, generates warnings.

4 - I've tested the code with several invalid session names and no errors or warnings were generated, everything worked and intended.

---

**References:**

[session.c Source Code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c)

Comment: I like your explanation but the algorithm can be improved:https://stackoverflow.com/a/58776699/1856214

Answer (score 3):

My bet would be, you were under attack at this time. This means someone manipulated your session cookie for example.

Since `session_start();` is a system function, I don't think it would generate invalid ids.

In my opinion, option 2 is the best. But if I remember correct, you need to set a custom error handler for this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27247721/2441442) seems better for me:

```
$ok = @session_start();
if(!$ok){
   //Hello Hacker ;)
   session_regenerate_id(true); // replace the Session ID
   session_start(); 
}
```

Comment: We get it once or twice a day, which makes no sense and the pages for the custom plugin only members can see so I don't get how it can be under attack. Why/what are they trying to do and moreover how do I prevent it?

Comment: The above code should definitve prevent this. But as always, never trust the userinput. Think about Session Hijacking etc. Are you sure, this code is not executed for any user? Once or twice a day is not often in case of an attack. You're lucky ;) Even if you think, you are not big enough, you use a cms system that is ;) You can try to add `error_log($_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']);` in `!$ok` path. I develop PHP since about 10 years. Never got generated an id that is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

I like the explanation of [Pedro Lobito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024310/1856214) but the algorithm can be improved:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && 0 === preg_match('/^[-,a-zA-Z0-9]{1,128}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
}

if ('' === session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```