# Drupal 7 fresh install shows session error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal

I've installed a Drupal7 CMS (v7.59). During the installation and on the login page, there is an error message as below:

```
Warning: session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in drupal_session_start() (line 287 of /xx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx/includes/session.inc).
```

I'm not able to login with my admin username and password (set during installation).

I've tried the followings:

- no cookie_domain set in settings.php
- rewrite apache module enabled
- browser cache cleared
- sessions and cache tables are empty in DB
- there are no custom modules, only core modules and themes

Some details:
 - PHP 5.6.35
 - Apache webserver
 - MySQL 5.7.21

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

maybe take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are/16318456#16318456/). i believe its related.

Comment: Thanks, I've already read this, but I do not think editing Drupal core script would be the best solution.